# Symmetry detection in images in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, symmetry

I'm working with an algorithm to detect symmetries in an irregular object, I'm using only Python with nunmpy and matplotlib, no possibility to use OpenCv, after I rotate my object along the principal axes, I get something like that [rotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fdDQ.png)

Then I wrote an algorithm which evaluate horizontal and vertical symmetries and make an average of the two:

def symmetry(self, mat):

mat is the matrix of coordinates of the points of my binary image

```
    coords = np.around(mat) #coordinates are rounded 
    i, j = coords.shape
    x, y = coords

    horizontal = 0
    vertical = 0



    for k in range(j):    
        for m in range(k, j):
            if(x[k] == x[m] and y[k] == -y[m]):
                horizontal += 1            
            if((x[k] == -x[m] and y[k] == y[m]):
                vertical += 1

    symmetry = (horizontal + vertical)/ j


    print('The symmetry index is:')
    print(symmetry)

    return
```

Since I wanted to evaluate the symmetry counting if each pixels has a correspondent with respect to the horizontal and the vertical axis I rounded the coordinates to integers, the problem is that if I test my algorithm with a cirlce, from which I expect perfect symmetry, I get about 0.5, the maximum value should be 1. 
Can somebody suggest a better metrics for evaluating the symmeytry in this situation or improve my code, In your opininon my solution should work?

Comment: Can you provide an example list of coordinates? What is the order of x and y for your circle test?

Comment: The coordinates are simply a list of points obtained after a rotation, since the original coordinates are multiplied by a transformation matrix, they are float numbers, that's why I rounded them, the first row represents the x coordinates and the second the y.

Comment: A guess is that you have not set the horizontal center line. You should find the center x of all points. Then measure the x-offsets from the x-center along each row for the left and right points and find their differences. Then repeat similarly for the vertical center and vertical offsets from the center line.

Comment: I can't understand, the image is centered at (0,0) look at the picture